# Read the column value extract the substring and over write the substring value

Tags: c#, excel

I am copying data from one excel sheet to another to compare. I need only date but in the columns date plus time is present. So write the code to iterate through the column fetch the substring and write .
Tried Code

```
        int nColumns = ws2.UsedRange.Columns.Count;
        int nRows = ws2.UsedRange.Rows.Count;

        for (int i = 3; i < nRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 2; j < nColumns; j++)
            {
                string order_date = ws2.Columns[i, "A" + j];
                string order_date_2 = order_date.Substring(9);
                ws2.Columns[i, "A2"] = order_date_2;
            }
        }
```

Comment: parse to a datetime and then ToShortDateTime()?

Comment: What _specifically_ doesn't work?

Comment: throwing exceptoion.

    System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException : Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Stack Trace
   at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
   at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.get__Default(Object RowIndex, Object ColumnIndex)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your problem is the fact that you only specify a single value for Substring() which would then default to that value being used as the Start index for the substring.  Try adding a zero as the first parameter as well as the current variable for the length like this:

```
string order_date_2 = order_date.Substring(0, 9);
```